# Having trouble with remote folder actions with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, remote-access

So I have an Applescript to help with naming photo's appropriately for data entry to assign it to a Unique ID.  Since we're using Mac's this is done in AppleScript.  This works great but it's only for one machine. What is now needed is to work on multiple machines. What I want to do is put the photos on our server and have the client machines do the action on the folder from there.

**The problem** I am currently having is that the script does not authenticate the user and does not run the script even though the info is correct. Am I doing this correctly?

```
tell application "Finder" of machine "eppc://user:password@server.local"
set renameFiles to the selection
set inventoryFiles to every file in folder (((path to documents folder) as text) &   "Inventory Photos")
set currentIndex to the count of inventoryFiles
repeat with i from 1 to the count of renameFiles
    set currentFile to (item i of renameFiles)
    set new_name to ((10000 + currentIndex + i) as text) & ".jpg"
        set name of currentFile to "a" & new_name
end repeat
end tell
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: if you take out the username and password and only run for example: tell application "Finder" of machine "eppc://server.local" to say "hello".   Do you get a password and user name prompt. Also this is a better way of doing it since the user can check the save in keychain